# How do I trigger a formula with a ComboBox that's ListFillRange is from a two column table?

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

Table: Column one values are strings. Column two values are numerical. I want to select the string value from a dropdown which will trigger a formula in a specific cell that will pull the corresponding numerical value into a simple formula that multiplies that value by a user input into an adjacent cell.

Here is the basic idea that I cannot get to work:

```
Private Sub ActivtyM_Change()

Range("C3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]" * Sheets("OtherSheet").Cells(ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1, 2).Value

End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested):

```
Private Sub ActivtyM_Change()

Range("C3").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*" & Sheets("OtherSheet").Cells(ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1, 2).Value

End Sub
```

Or, if you don't need formulas:

```
Private Sub ActivtyM_Change()

    Range("C3").Value = Range("B3").Value * Sheets("OtherSheet").Cells(ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1, 2).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Both throw a "Subscript out of range" Run-time error '9' which is the same thing I was getting before

Comment: Place a breakpoint in that line and query all relevant variables in the Immediate Window. Like: 1) ?Sheets("OtherSheet").Name 2)?ComboBox1.ListIndex 3) ActiveSheet.Name

Comment: @slurrr did you do that?

Comment: honestly, I am horrible with excel. Right now I am googling how to debug. I am good with adding stops but not sure how to query or even where to start. You know a good place to learn about that?

Comment: in the VBE editor place the cursor in the offending line and press F9. This will place the breakpoint. Then press F5 and have the code Run. It'll stop at the breakpoint. Then open the Immediate Window (CTRL+G) , type `?Sheets("OtherSheet").Name` and press return. And watch the result. Similarly with `?ComboBox1.ListIndex` and `?ActiveSheet.Name`

Comment: apparently the problem is in the `?Sheets("OtherSheet").Name` it's coming up as unknown name

Comment: which is also one of the most common causes of the "Subscript out of range" error. While still in the breakpoint (i.e. with the error ruling) go on typing in the immediate window `?ActiveSheet.Name` and return and  `?ActiveWorkbook.Name`  and return. Moreover, are you working with more than one workbook?

Comment: those both call out sheet2 and current workbook respectively. I do have multiple workbooks open, but that doesn't seem to be causing an issue. Either way I closed them and still get same

Comment: does your macro requires open workbooks other than the one it resides in? in other words what's the minimum workbooks scenario to have your macro begin and what other workbooks are opened/processed by it?

Comment: The table is on sheet1, is there a better way to call that out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115425/discussion-between-user3598756-and-slurrr).

Comment: You'd better edit your post and add more info: what is `ActivtyM`? Is `Combobox1`the name of a userform or a sheet combobox ? and so on...